# How do I prevent <input disabled> from occurring

Tags: wordpress, passwords

I have a wordpress website on which the sign up button only becomes enabled if the password strength is "strong". I'm awful with wordpress so I have spent hours attempting to find the "disabled" option in the password's  button tag without any luck. I've also removed one of the 'must-use' plugins from my wp-content/theme/mytheme folder and it no longer appears in the wordpress site admin's plugin section but the problem still persists.

https://accsesnj.org/login/

I would appreciate any help. 
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try comment row 292 in @accsesnj.org/wp-content/themes/accses/js/app.js

```
//$('.sign-up-form input[type=submit]').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
```

Comment: Hey thank you! The problem turned out to be on line 243 where the pass strength was initially == 4. I changed it to 3. Thanks for the help!
One last question. How did you get to read the app.js file?

Comment: Hi. Just opened source page view-source:https://accsesnj.org/
and searched .js files with ".sign-up-form" string

Comment: Thanks. How do you arrange the code in that javascript file? For me it all shows up in one straight line and it's difficult to read that.